# Can you overclock an unrooted Galaxy Tab?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-tab, overclocking

Can you increase the speed of an unrooted the Galaxy Tab, like an app for example?

Answer (score 1):

Almost certainly not.  Unless Samsung has provided a way for you to do this — highly unlikely due to warranty and user experience issues — you'll need root and probably a custom kernel that supports overclocking.